# What is best way of getting out of a twin arm wrap?

Tags: multiple-attackers, escapes

A gang in town is using restraining methods commonly used by prison officers. They learnt this from experience in jail. They would use the common arm wrap and, if necessary, put the person on the ground, then do what they want with the person.

My question is: What is the best way to get out of a twin arm wrap, with two people on either side? Or better still when you are fully on the ground?

[Twin arm wrap](http://youtu.be/CFnQ2R7FS5E?t=114)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming avoiding the gang, and verbal discouragement had failed I would use this technique from my training.  It is called Kiri Gote (cutting restraint)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hE57Fy4PJvI&t

As soon as one person attempts the wrist hold shown in the video I would lock my elbow to my body and move my wrist up to this position with a turning step to set up the technique.  Once they are kneeling a kick to the head or body should finish the fight for that attacker.  I would then move on to the next attacker and use punches and kicks.

Basically you have to make a call as to whether the attack merits a punch to the face.  It depends on the situation and is your call to make.

Edit: Second video in english.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JD2_UtOQp_A

Comment: Yes, i see the logic. Their technique for restaining works on grabbing the wrist so your counter this.

Comment: @AsanRamzan But better still just hit them before they grab the wrist.... Depends just how violent they are.